# Haskell runCommand in Windows

Tags: windows, haskell

As a simple exercise, I'm trying to change the prompt in Win7's Command Prompt window with the following little program:

```
module Main where
 import System.Environment
 import System.Process 

 p :: String -> String 
 p name = "Prompt " ++ name ++ "\r\n"

 main :: IO ()
 main = do
     putStrLn ("Give me a name:")
     name <- getLine
     putStrLn (p name)
     pid <- runCommand $ p name
```

Although it runs fine in the Command Prompt window, it does not actually change the prompt. Entering the same command on the command line by hand does change it.  When I use "system" (which returns an exit code) rather than "runCommand" (which just returns a pid) it gives "ExitSuccess", but still doesn't change the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Haskell issue per-se, just that you can't easily write a program in any language that will change the environment of its parent process.

In your scenario the prompt is controlled by the `PROMPT` environment variable, and the "parent process" is the Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) that you launched your Haskell program from.

I would suggest that instead of trying to alter the parent `cmd.exe` process, you spawn a new `cmd.exe` (also with `runCommand`) after you have changed the prompt. You should wait for this process to finish with `waitForProcess` on the PID returned from `runCommand`, otherwise your Haskell program will exit with the child shell still running.

You will probably also have to switch from running the `Prompt` command to actually changing the `PROMPT` environment variable directly in your Haskell process, because what actually happens when you run the `Prompt` command as above is that a new `cmd.exe` is started just to run that command, so the environment change is immediately thrown away.

You can edit the environment with the [setenv package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/setenv-0.1.1/docs/System-SetEnv.html).

Comment: Thank you Ganesh.  I installed and tried the setenv package as you suggested, using:
   
    setEnv "PROMPT" name
(also tried setEnv "%PROMPT%" name)
no luck; so, is there a separate PROMPT variable for each process, or is it system-wide??

Happy New Year, by the way!

Comment: Did you also spawn a new command prompt (something like `runCommand "cmd.exe"`)? I just tested my idea briefly in ghci and it seems to work fine. `setEnv "PROMPT" name` is the correct form.

Comment: Environment is generally per process, and passed to newly spawned child processes. Changes won't be passed up to parent processes or to unrelated processes. You can perhaps check Windows docs for a registry entry or something where the user's preferred prompt is stored long term. In Unix/Cygwin `bash` for example, it would be in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks, guys; amusingly the two prompts alternated, in the same Command Prompt window.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that `runCommand` spawns the process and returns immediately, so it's still running when the program exits and ends up interleaved with the parent command prompt. I edited my answer to recommend use of `waitForProcess`. You might also be able to use `system` or `rawSystem` directly.